# Cloud foundry : cf login authentication issue 'credentials were rejected'

Tags: authentication, cloud-foundry

I am trying to login to bluemix using `cf login` command from git bash and I am facing credentials were rejected issue. Please see the below command and and error message -

Tried commands -

1. `cf login -u 'myemail' -p 'mypassword'`
2. `cf login -myemail  --sso`

Error message - 
see image - [error message Credentials were rejected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmKSO.png)

Message -

Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.

Comment: I think you may be using different API endpoint..

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/171).  The easiest fix is to not use Git bash.  Use the Windows Command Prompt or Power Shell.

Watch the issue to see if/when this is resolved.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I faced this issue too. After several "hit-n-try" iterations, the following worked for me: 1. cf login -u 'myemail' 2. On the prompt, enter 'password'.